# Is there a way to set DNS options in AWS ECS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, containers, amazon-ecs

Docker allows us to push dns options through docker run, using --dns-opt switch. For some reason, I am unable to see this in AWS ECS. Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately it seems `--dns-opt` is currently an unsupported flag in ECS task definitions.

See https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/issues/502 for a fuller list of unsupported Docker run parameters (albeit some of these flags are now supported.